How to filter tensorflow tuple dataset?
import tensorflow as tf

# Create dummy data
image_data = [tf.constant([1]), tf.constant([2]), tf.constant([3])]
caption_data = [tf.constant([10]), tf.constant([20]), tf.constant([30])]
target_data = [tf.constant([100]), tf.constant([200]), tf.constant([300])]

# Create a dataset from the dummy data
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((image_data, caption_data), target_data))

# Define a filter function that checks a simple condition on the target tensor
def filter_funct(data):
    ((image_tensor, caption_tensor), target_tensor) = data
    return target_tensor > 150

# Apply the filter function
filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(filter_funct)

# Print the filtered dataset
for ((image_tensor, caption_tensor), target_tensor) in filtered_dataset:
    print("Image Tensor:", image_tensor.numpy())
    print("Caption Tensor:", caption_tensor.numpy())
    print("Target Tensor:", target_tensor.numpy())

I wanted to slice for some corrupted images but I can't use tf.filter correctly. Above is just a dummy data. it is not working.
this is the error code
TypeError: outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__filter_funct() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


If you have tuples in your dataset, you have to expect them in the function or lambda call:
def filter_funct(data, labels):
    return tf.reduce_all(labels > 150)

# equivalent lambda call:
filtered_ds = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_all(y > 150))

Without reduce_all, the function produced a ValueError:

ValueError: Invalid predicate. predicate must return a tf.bool scalar tensor, but its return type is TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.bool, name=None).

labels > 150 produced a tuple of one element (1,), because the labels are in this tuple format. reduce_all converts the tuple to a single scalar value.

Seems like an issue concerning the definition of the filter_funct() function and how the dataset is defined. The dataset object has 2 elements but you are currently passing them as one unique tuple. Maybe there is a better way, but, since your filter only considers the target_tensor values, I would try filtering before creating the dataset as follows:
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf

# Create dummy data
image_data = [tf.constant([1]), tf.constant([2]), tf.constant([3])]
caption_data = [tf.constant([10]), tf.constant([20]), tf.constant([30])]
target_data = [tf.constant([100]), tf.constant([200]), tf.constant([300])]


indexes = tf.where(target_tensor > 150).numpy()

image_data = image_data[indexes]
caption_data = caption_data [indexes]
target_data = target_data [indexes]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((image_data, caption_data), target_data))

# Print the filtered dataset
for ((image_tensor, caption_tensor), target_tensor) in filtered_dataset:
    print("Image Tensor:", image_tensor.numpy())
    print("Caption Tensor:", caption_tensor.numpy())
    print("Target Tensor:", target_tensor.numpy())

